# How to add some text to an existing message box in wxpython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, messagebox

I'm new to wxpython. I want to add some text to an existing message box using wxpython GUI programming. I searched on the net, but I couldn't any useful info. Could you please help me with this issue?

My goal is to run a code and then print some text during code running into a window.

Thanks,

---

I want to have something like this one:

```
    outPut = 'Simulation is done' 
    wx.MessageBox(outPut, "Results")
    newText = 'The results are:\n' #add this text to previous MessageBox
```

Comment: What is the type of the existing text in the textbox? Is it `StaticText`? Is it a `TextCtrl` box?

Comment: It is just an ordinary text. Sth like this: `outPut = 'Simulation is done\'`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with MessageBox, but what about using ProgressDialog?  I updated the code and tested it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
print(wx.VERSION_STRING)

import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc


class abc(sc.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        super(abc, self).__init__(parent, id, 'Frame aka window')
        cpane = self.GetContentsPane()

        button1 = wx.Button(cpane, label="ProgressDialog 1 sample")
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pdlg1)

        button1 = wx.Button(cpane, label="ProgressDialog 2 sample")
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pdlg2)


    def pdlg1(self, evt):
        dlgPro = wx.ProgressDialog(u"Simulation progress 1",
                                   u"It is starting",
                                   3,
                                   None,
                                   wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_APP_MODAL)
        # do something
        dlgPro.Update(1, u"first one is done")
        # do something
        wx.Yield()
        wx.Sleep(1)
        dlgPro.Update(2, u"second one is done")
        # do something
        wx.Yield()
        wx.Sleep(1)
        dlgPro.Update(3, u"we are finished")

    def pdlg2(self, evt):
        dlgPro = wx.ProgressDialog(u"Simulation progress 2",
                                   u"It is starting",
                                   -1,
                                   None,
                                   wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_APP_MODAL)
        # do something
        dlgPro.Pulse(u"first one is done")
        # do something
        wx.Yield()
        wx.Sleep(1)
        dlgPro.Pulse(u"second one is done")
        # do something
        wx.Yield()
        wx.Sleep(1)
        dlgPro.Pulse(u"we are finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = abc(None, -1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ProgressDialog.html?highlight=progress

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, when I use the `ProgressDialog` and after dialog shows the last message, the original program stopped to work, I don't know why? Do I have to put something after last `dlgPro.Update()` part?

Comment: How are you displaying the progress dialog? Are you using `showModal()`?

Comment: I updated the sample code, now you can run it.  The difference is in the first sample one defines the steps (3 in this case) where in the second one does not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add text to a text box, you will have to add some sort of text object to the frame. For example

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      wx.Frame.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.text = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World!")
```

creates a frame that has the text "Hello, World" in it. It is static text, meaning the user cannot change it. If you wanted text that can be changed, look at `wx.TextCtrl`

Comment: I want something like in my original post, the last part.